# assign method to event for multiple controls using jquery

Tags: jquery, client-side

I have a few textboxes with the same class, and want to assign a method on the focus event for them all.
This does not work:

```
$('.postal').onfocus = setLeft();
```

In dev-tools the controls' class is '`postal x-form-text x-form-field`', so would that make the above jquery not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
$('.postal').on('focus',setLeft);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked straight away. My jquery is very limited: do you have any web resources I can use to sharpen up?

Comment: @callisto - they have excellent documentation. for example, if you would have googled jquery on focus, the `.focus()` page would be tops. from an experimenting standpoint, the `.on()` selector can be used for any on event ... `onhover`, `onclick`, etc. you can even bind multiple handlers in a single `.on()` declaration!

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to steal any thunder, just providing additional information about the use of the `.on()` handler.

You can combine it with several other handlers to consolidate code and minimize DOM impact! For example:

```
$('.postal').on({
    focus:setLeft, // predefined functions can be used as long as there are no parameters passed
    click:function(){
        alert('clicked');
    },
    blur:function(){
        hideMe($(this)); // for functions that pass in parameters, encase them in separate functions
    }
});
```

This is an incredibly powerful and efficient way to utilize `.on()`, because the DOM is only scraped once. This is better than doing different binds using the shorthand of `.focus()`, `.click()`, and `.blur()`, which would require the DOM being scraped with each binding.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$('.postal').on('focus',setLeft);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut as well

`$('.postal').focus(setLeft);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a basic.

You can assign any method in the `callback` when using `jQuery`.

Most of times, we use `functions` this way:

```
$('.postal').on('focus', function(){ /* Do something */ });
```

But this is also valid:

```
$('.postal').on('focus', hello);

function hello(){ alert('hello'); };
```

So, I think the second way fits your requirement to assign a method for multiple controls with the same `class`.